# Removing the nth index character from a non-empty string in python

Tags: python, function

I have a problem in this code. When I declare `str1="ibrahim"` and want to remove an nth index, it removes all `i` letters from my `str1` for index `n = 0`.

```
def remove_char(str1,n):
    for i in [str1]:
        if i != n:
            x = str1.replace(str1[n],"")
            print(x)
        else:
            print(i)

x = input("please entre a string")
y = int(input("please entre n'th character you want to remove"))
remove_char(x,y)
```

Could you please correct the code and explain why it malfunctions?

Comment: You are looping through a 1 element list.  So in your example :  i will be str1 and iterate one time in your loop.  also, your if statement is checking if str1 == n, which will never be true, unless you pass in an integer into the variable of str1.  

You are simply trying to splice out the character with the index value, so why not use list slicing?

def remove_char(str1,n):
    firstPart = str1[:n]
    lastPart = str1[n+1:]
    return firstPart + lastPart

Answer (score 2):

Slicing and Concatenation is the best way in my opinion.

Say your string is

```
s = 'StackOverflow'
```

and you want to remove 'O' from the said string, i.e, the 5th character, so you can do something like,

```
k = s[:5] + s[6:]
print(k)
```

Comment: thank you so much. it is very short and clean

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def remove(string, n):  
  first = string[:n]   
  last = string[n+1:]  
  return first + last
```